# case when then IN

Tags: sql, oracle

below code does not work, please advise.

```
SELECT *
 FROM TBL_REASON_MAP A
WHERE case when V_ID = 3 then 'A' else to_char(a.type_id) end IN
      case when V_ID = 3 then 'A' else '(2,3)' end;
```

below is OK:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TBL_REASON_MAP A
 WHERE case when  V_ID = 3 then 'A' else to_char(a.type_id) end IN
       case when  V_ID = 3 then 'A' else '2' end;
```

note: V_ID is a variable to be passed a value in plsql block. If V_ID = 3 then it will return all data available, but if it's not it will return data with a.type_id in (2,3) only.

e.g.
V_ID = 4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QQ9y.png)

Comment: please update your question according to this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Boolean are better for condition where clause not case statement.. Please show sample data and your expected output..

Comment: A case expression's different return types must be compatible. `'A'` and `(2,3)` aren't.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `a.type_id` contains values like `2`, `3`, `4` etc. The first `case()` returns a **string** of `(2,3)`. It's a single value so the IN becomes an equality test. `2` does not equal `'(2,3)`. Therefore the first code does not work. Whereas the second `case()` returns a single value `2` which can be matched to a value in `a.type_id`.

---

> "anyway if V_ID = 3 then it will return all data available, but if its not, it will return data with a.type_id in (2,3)"

As other people have commented this is easy to implement with regular Boolean operations without the need for `case()` at all:

```
SELECT *
 FROM TBL_REASON_MAP A
WHERE V_ID = 3 
or (V_ID != 3 
    and a.type_id  IN (2,3));
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, Ive attached the sample data. this sample query will run on a plsql block(apologies, i should have provided a plsql block, in a hurry Im currently testing it in SQL.), anyway if V_ID = 3 then it will return all data available, but if its not, it will return data with a.type_id in (2,3) only.

Comment: *"in a hurry Im currently testing it in SQL"* On StackOverflow we get answers quicker if we slow down and ask a clear and complete answer ;-)

Comment: thanks I'll keep that in mind. :) actually ive got an idea on your first answer, that case when function, the IN becomes an equality test, so I was able to formulate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So far the solution Ive got is below:

```
Declare

    V_ID number;

begin

    V_ID := 4;

    SELECT *
      FROM TBL_REASON_MAP A
     WHERE case when V_ID = 3 then 'A' else to_char(a.type_id) end >=
           case when V_ID = 3 then 'A' else '2' end
       and case when V_ID = 3 then 'A' else to_char(a.type_id) end !=
           case when V_ID = 3 then 'A' else '0' end;

END;
```

Comment: I updated my case-less solution to incorporate V_ID. It's concise and comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest logic is:

```
WHERE ( V_ID = 3 OR a.type_id IN (2, 3) );
```

There is no need for a `CASE` expression.